# Do I need to close browser instance (e.g. Chrome, Firefox) after launching it through Coded UI?

Tags: coded-ui-tests

I am trying to do cross browser testing using Coded UI (with the help of selenium components and required binaries).
My code is like following:

```
BrowserWindow.CurrentBrowser = "Chrome;
{ // ...
// Code to perform some actions on browser
}
```

When I launch test after selecting current browser, the browser window opens and actions are performed. Then the window is closed. 
Is Coded UI handling proper closure of browser instance automatically or I need to handle this in cleanup method?

Answer (score 2):

If you need to log out of your application to ensure it cleans up it's session management, you need to manually click the "log out" button (or whatever). CodedUI does not handle that for you. Other than that, it seems to me to be the normal behavior for CodedUI to close the browser after the test is finished. See these posts:

[How do I keep the browser open after a coded ui test finishes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14426202/how-do-i-keep-the-browser-open-after-a-coded-ui-test-finishes?rq=1)
[Coded UI: App gets closed after each test even with CloseOnPlaybackCleanup set to false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32034851/coded-ui-app-gets-closed-after-each-test-even-with-closeonplaybackcleanup-set-t/33308485#33308485)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you mean by 'handling proper closure of browser instance', but CodedUI does close the browser automatically by default on IE as well as cross-browser on Firefox and Chrome.

If you did want to perform actions after each test but before CodedUI wrapped everything up you could add code to the "MyTestCleanup" method under the "Additional test attributes" region of your CodedUI test project.